# Executing shell script from different directory through Jenkins

Tags: shell, amazon-web-services, jenkins, centos

I want to execute my shell script kept in different directory with AWS user access (ec2-user) through Jenkins.

The installed Jenkins works under directory `/var/lib/jenkins`.

The scripts are in `/home/ec2-user/scripts`.

I have tried to change directory but it is not working!

Please help!

Comment: Where and how have you "_tried to change directory_"? How exactly is it "_not working_"? Any error message? Unexpected behaviour or result? More detailed questions usually lead to more detailed answers.

Comment: Build failing !
My directory path is appending to existing jenkins default path and thats why it is giving me error 'No such Directory / File' .

Comment: Please add the build's Console Log to your question.

Comment: Which command do you use to invoke the scripts? Do you use absolute path, relative path, or do you expect the scripts to be found through the PATH variable? Do they have the x-bit set?